# NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset and VirtualizationStackPanel containers rebuild

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have custom implementation of ICollectionView and I am using NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset event when I add many items (because it is faster than calling NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add for each element) the drawback of this is that VirtualizationStack panel is re-initializing its item containers when NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset is raised. This is virtualizationstackpanel base class Panel.cs.

```
// This method returns a bool to indicate if or not the panel layout is affected by this collection change
    internal virtual bool OnItemsChangedInternal(object sender, ItemsChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        switch (args.Action)
        {
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
                AddChildren(args.Position, args.ItemCount);
                break;
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove:
                RemoveChildren(args.Position, args.ItemUICount);
                break;
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace:
                ReplaceChildren(args.Position, args.ItemCount, args.ItemUICount);
                break;
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Move:
                MoveChildren(args.OldPosition, args.Position, args.ItemUICount);
                break;

            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset:
                ResetChildren();
                break;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

This affect the performance because the newly created item containers have its layout updated and that cause noticeable delay. My question is there a way to use 
NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset event and avoid this side effect of rebuilding items containers?

Comment: Create a custom panel that overrides the OnItemsChanged method and implement your own logic?

Comment: OnItemsChanged is private method.

Comment: No, it's `protected` and `virtual` which means that it can be overridden in derived classes.